# Why this is not working in :not() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently facing this problem where `:not(this)` is not working but is working when I specify the exact element selector. Please see my code sample below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').on('click', function(){
  
    $('p:not(this, .intro)').css('background', 'yellow');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside strings.

Comment: Could you explain what your code is supposed to do? Which element is supposed to become yellow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').on('click', function(){
    $('p:not(.intro)').not(this).css('background', 'yellow');    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Comment: So `$('p:not(.intro)')` is not accepting `this`?

Comment: When you provide `this` in quotes, it loses its meaning. $(this) is different from $('this'). Since you `:not` accepts string selectors, you have to use `.not`.

Comment: @Jonjie Correct.  `this` is a javascript variable, and the thing between the `$('` and `')` is a css selector.  You can't put a javascript variable inside a css selector like that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean `.not(this).not(".intro")` ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').on('click', function(){
  
    $('p').not(this).not(".intro").css('background', 'yellow');
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="intro">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<p>My best friend is Mickey.</p>
```

Comment: I've read some of the answers here in SO; they said it is better to use `p:not(this, .intro)` selector. Is there really any performance issue with using `.not()` ?

Comment: I don't know about performance, but at least this works, unlike the `:not` pseudo-selector. If you worry about performance, you should start with caching your `$('p')`